# SQL QUERY TO SHOW 2 COLUMN WITH DIFFERENT CONDITION

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have table like this in my database oracle.

WITEL-KATEGORI-MONTH

A------------R------------2

A------------S------------3

B------------S------------2

C------------T------------3

B------------T------------2

A------------T------------3

C------------S------------2

C------------S------------2

A------------S------------2

A------------S------------2

A------------S------------3

A------------S------------3

B------------S------------3

anyone have idea, what query that can show data like
this :

WITEL--COUNT-1--COUNT-2

A-----------3-----------5

B-----------1-----------2

C-----------2-----------2

First colum is witel, second colum is count of witel WHERE KATEGORI=S AND MONTH=3
but third column is count of all witel where KATEGORI=S. thank you

Comment: you need to use SUM(CASE WHEN .... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END). Try it. It is very easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation, which is using an aggregation function like `SUM()` with a `CASE` statement as an argument:

```
select witel,
       sum(case when KATEGORI = 'S' AND MONTH = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as count1,
       sum(case when KATEGORI = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) as count2
from table t
group by witel;
```